# Sliding VIEWS Approach. Advise needed. IPHONE + XCODE

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing application with sliding views, where user slides finger and new view appears. I have around 140 views to slide through.

I have tried initialy addSubview the problem I face was the rotation of the view
than I tried UINavigation controller where I'm pushing views.
but application crashes after 120 slider approx.

What is the best approach to appear views for my case

Comment: What are these views? Definitely UINavigationController isn't meant for this.

Comment: did you figure out a way to solve your problem??

Comment: Thanx Deepak, learner2010, yes I did Modal Views with CALayer transitions worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead [link](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-load-1000s-of-uiimageview-on.html)
The author talks about loading thousands of images and unloading them while not using them...

Comment: thanx. this actually really helpfull, will try it on my next project